# Job, scheduled with Cron, does not execute

Tags: shell, cron, solaris

I've scheduled to execute job.sh script, which contains the following commands:

```
date +"%D %r `echo Kitchen - job started`" >> /tmp/cron_job_1.log
sh /installations/data-integration/kitchen.sh -file /installations/etl/sync_job.kjb >> /tmp/cron_job_1.log
date +"%D %r `echo Kitchen - job completed`" >> /tmp/cron_job_1.log
```

Crontab record is:

```
0,3,4,5,6,8,10,11 * * * * sh /installations/etl_scripts/job.sh
```

'Job started' and 'job completed' timestamps are always successfully written to cron_job_1.log, it's a proof that scheduled job runs on time. But it seems that Pentaho transformation (../kitchen.sh) command does not run, because transformation does not proceeding and nothing is written to log file. Time between 'job started' and 'job ended' is 1 or 2 seconds, but transformation job should run at least 10 seconds.

When i run command  `sh /installations/data-integration/kitchen.sh -file /installations/etl/sync_job.kjb >> /tmp/cron_job_1.log` independently from console transformation job works as expected and writes to log.

All paths and permissions of involved files seems to be correct.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have a big post on how to debug cron when it exhibits buggy behavior: http://serverfault.com/questions/425397/cron-stopped-working-partially-working/449639#449639

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to crontab [FAQ](http://www.unix.com/answers-frequently-asked-questions/13527-cron-crontab.html) : cron sets up only a sparse environment, so your environment variables are not accessible in cron script. You have to set up environment variables in your job.sh script.

Comment: Setting of env. variables added to the top of the script. Works fine now. Thanks!